# time-out asp.net gives error

Tags: asp.net, session, timeout

When a user loggs in on the website, he can do what ver he wants(Which is correct). But if he's away for a few minutes somekind of `time-out` happens. This is causing the following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

He thros this on the session which shows the username:

`Label1.Text = "Welkom " + Session("Naam").ToString()`

Any ideas on how to fix it? Or how to show it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options;

Increase the Session timeout. So where ever you are creating the session, you can set the timeout.

```
Session.Timeout = 30;
```

Or set the timeout in the web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Or you can check to make sure that the session value exists.

c#

```
if ( Session["Naam"] != null ){ ... }
```

vb.net

```
If Not Session("Naam") Is Nothing Then
```